# How to use Vimeo Player NPM package in script js

Tags: laravel, npm, vimeo-player

I have a laravel blade component, within which I have a script tag.
I've installed the Vimeo player package via.

`npm install @vimeo/player --save`

How do I now use the package in my `<script>` tags inside the component?

If I do this `var player = new Vimeo.Player('custom-player', options);`

It doesn't work as Vimeo is undefined.

Comment: Do you have to use it in a `<script>` tag? Can you not use it in your `app.js` file and then use mix to compile that file and use it in the browser?

Comment: I have done this in app.js `import Player from '@vimeo/player';` and I'm doing this in my script tags, but I'm guessing that won't work. The thing is, that the video component runs optionally based on a condition, I don't have to render the video at all times.

Comment: Ok the simple solution (which I do not personally recommend but it would work) would be to do `import Player from '@vimeo/player';` and then do `window.Player = Player` and then after you've included your `app.js` file you should be able to do `var player = new Player(...)`

Comment: Tried that, but getting: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Player is not defined` after I do `var player = new Player('custom-player', options);` in the scripts.

Have both of this included in app.js
`
import Player from '@vimeo/player';
window.Player = Player;
`

And appjs is also included in mix.
`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');`

Comment: I can get the Player in console, but I was loading the video first, so maybe it hasn't loaded by then and maybe the script tags run before the app.js.

Comment: If I include the player after a while, it works. Anything I can do to make sure my script tags run after app.js has run?

Comment: You should have a `<script src='{{ mix('app.js') }}></script>` somewhere in your layout. Just make sure your scripts run after this  script has ran

Comment: Thanks. Also one more thing, what's the ideal way to do this if I have to use it in a script? Should I just include the Vimeo script, is that more preferable in this case?

Comment: All your JavaScript code should be written in .js files in your resources and then transpiled through your webpack.mix.js file.  You can include them in your `app.js` or transpile them separately and then include them in their own scripts.

Comment: I'm doing this for the player within the component:
`var options = { id: {{ $component['media'] }},...` 
How can I get that in the custom js file that I create.
That would change based upon the component that's currently on the page.